# can i use snapshot with (where) query

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

im using stream builder, which displays snapshot data, but i want to use **where** query over snapshot, ( i want stream builder to print only approved restaurants from firestore)
is it possible in flutter or not
this is the code

```
CollectionReference restaurants = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Restaurants");
child: StreamBuilder(
  stream: restaurants.snapshots(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    return ListView(
      children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((restaurants) {
        // Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
        return Card(
          child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 150),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.06,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 8,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            color: Colors.white38,
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                image: AssetImage(AppImages.foodImg))),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 200,),
                      Text(restaurants['restaurantName'], style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,fontSize: 12),),
                      Text(restaurants['address'],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11),),
                      
                    ],

                  ),
                ],
              )
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  },
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to show only the restaurants who have a field `approved` with a value of `true` in the UI. You can do so with:

```
stream: restaurants.where('approved', equalTo: true).snapshots(),
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [executing queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries).